# Purchase a list of LEGO parts

Tags: shopping, pick-a-brick, bricklink

If I have a list of LEGO parts (exported from LEGO Digital Designer or Bricksmith) is there an easy way to purchase all of the parts either on LEGO's Pick a Brick or on Bricklink?

I know that I can go through the list one by one and order the pieces but I was hoping that there might be some tool where I can upload a list and have all of the parts automatically added to my cart.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this for Pick-a-brick (which sports an antiquated UI) requires some fairly advanced hacking. See [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-can-i-automate-orders-from-lego-pick-a-brick?rq=1). It's unfortunate that there is no simple interface for importing composite sets of bricks.

Answer (score -3):

With bricklink you can convert to xml with ie ms Excel

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer by explaining the process or the major steps?